# Redirect all (sub-)routes in .htaccess and keeping url results in error 404 on index page

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am trying to mask a specific route (and all subroutes following that) of Domain A with Domain B. So basically if someone accesses "DomainB.com" he should be brought to "DomainA.com/page/1". And when someone accesses "DomainB.com/about", he should be brought to "DomainA.com/page/1/about". However, in the browser there should always be "DomainB.com/about".

I have achieved this by using the following line in the .htaccess inside the root folder of Domain B:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainB\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://DomainA.com/page/1/$1 [P]
```

This is working fine now for all subroutes (e.g. DomainB.com/about). However the index route (DomainB.com) is giving me an error 404 and I cannot figure out why.

I am using Laravel 7 for this project. The htaccess of DomainA.com looks as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Allow access to font files for known hosts
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(DomainB.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
            Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
            Header merge Vary Origin
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Gzip text compression
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

      # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>

    # Redirect to non-index.php url.
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
      RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong with my .htaccess? Or is there a way to keep the rule that I wrote and write a second rule that redirects ONLY the index route to "DomainA.com/page/1"?

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Does directly accessing `https://DomainA.com/page/1/` work - or does it only work without the trailing slash? If the latter, then you probably will have to handle this case separately.

Comment: Yes, accessing `https://DomainA.com/page/1/` as well as `https://DomainA.com/page/1` is working fine.

Comment: And if you replace the `P` flag with `R=302` - do you get _redirected_ to the proper location then, when trying to access the root of B?

Comment: Yes! As soon as i change the redirect method I get to the correct page. Unfortunately that is not a valid solution for me, since I must keep the DomainB.com in the URL.

Comment: Yes, I know - just trying to narrow down where it goes wrong here. I’d continue by checking the logfiles for domain A next - check what that incoming request from the proxy looks like, and how it might differ from the “normal” request made for that URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, however it is not the ideal solution for me.

Firstly, I declared a new route called "/index" pointing to the same function the "/" route points to. Like this:

```
Route::get('/index', 'PageController@index'); // the /page/{id} part is done in the group above with model binding
```

Then I added the following lines to my .htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} DomainB\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://DomainB.com/index [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the user from DomainB.com to DomainB.com/index, which works. I don't know if this is an ideal solution however, since altering the index link might be bad for SEO... It is definitely bad for SEO on DomainA.com, because now there are multiple ways to get to the index page.